# Help with construction problems

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I have three construction problems that I'm trying to solve.

Construct triangles $ABC$ when

1. Given $h_a = 3.5$ and $\angle A = \angle C = 50 \deg$
2. Given $h_a = 3.5$, $h_b = 4$ and $\angle C = 50 \deg$

I'm really struggling where to even begin on both of these problems.

Comment: $a)$ The height $h_a$ together with the point C, form a triangle with an angle of $90°$. You know all angles and a side, so you can easily construct this partial triangle. $b)$ is tougher.

Comment: @Peter Ah yes, I have noticed this. I was simply unaware of how to utilize that fact. How would I go about constructing a right triangle when I know one angle and the opposite side? Do I have to construct the remaining angle and use that?

Comment: Just calculate the remaining angle. Another possibility is to draw an angle at some point with $50°$ and constructing the parallel through $A$, but this is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: $b)$ Start with the triangle formed by $h_a$ and the point $C$. Again, you know all angles of this partial triangle and a side. Construct also the parallel to AC with distance $h_b$. So, you find $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a)$

The height $h_a$ together with point $C$ form a triangle with angle of $90°$.
You know all the angles and one side of this triangle.

$b)$

The height $h_a$ together with point $C$ form a triangle with angle $90°$ as in $a)$. To find $B$, draw the parallel to AC with distance $h_b$.